# Dynamic pipe in Modelica

Tags: pipe, fluid, modelica

I can't understand the benefit of the nNodes parameter in the .Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe component.
How can we choose this parameter and from the point of view of physics, what does it mean?

Now, i`m trying to realize, how this model works to use it in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nNodes` determines the order of the dynamic response — for instance for a change in inlet temperature.

Setting `nNode=1` gives a first-order response where the outlet temperature starts rising immediately after a step change in input temperature. This is also the case if the pipe is very long.

Setting `nNodes=200` gives a 200th order response which looks like a time delay followed by a steeper rise in outlet temperature. This is closer to the true physical response of a (long) pipe where you would expect a delayed response depending on pipe length and flow velocity. A high value of `nNodes` increases computational time, so you should make a tradeoff between physical accuracy (if this aspect is important for your application) and computational speed.

In either case the pipe *time constant* is almost identical.

Alternative pipe models, such as the `PlugFlowPipe` model in Modelica Buildings Library implement the delay with the `spatialDistribution` operator which reduces the model order and is suitable for "transmission line" pipe models.

The figures below shows the effect of varying `nNodes` between 1 and 200. The number of equations in the model varies between 149 and 13283.

[image: Diagram]
[image: Step responses]

Comment: I guess you mean `spatialDistribution`, not `spatialDiscretization`.

Comment: @marco right. I'll correct it

Comment: Thanks, it helps me.
Do I understand correctly that we divide the pipe into several parts, where the equations for the conservation of mass and energy are solved separately and the temperature change is due to the boundary conditions obtained from the solutions of the equations for each part?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: @DaniilUdalov I have updated my answer with a graphical example.

Comment: @Rene Just Nielsen, thank you!! It really helps me)